# Getting error "Class 'DOMDocument' not found" in PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm getting an error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/embed/embed/src/Request.php:246
```

I found online that I have to install php-xml and php-dom. First, I checked my php version:

```
/var/www/html# php -v
PHP 7.1.33-17+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2020 14:46:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33-17+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Then, I installed php-xml and php-dom:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-dom
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

And restarted nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

But it's still showing the first error. I'm three hours into this and it's driving me insane.

Comment: after installation, have you turned on the extension?

Comment: have you restarted the php-fpm service?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I've checked that it's enabled

Comment: @MaryNfs Yes, I also restarted php-fpm

Comment: Anyone any ideas?